# Are SSH remote connection passwords encrypted?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, security

When I try to connect to my SSH remotely, will the password I send to authenticate my user account be encrypted when it's transferred over the internet?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580978/ssh-when-logging-in-is-the-password-in-plain-text-sniffable Short answer: The password will be encrypted.

Comment: I'm not sure if SSH uses Diffie Hellman but it's an example of how an encrypted session can be setup over a insecure channel.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the password sent will be encrypted.  In the bootstrapping phase of the SSH session the SSH server sends the client its public key which the client uses to encrypt the key to some symmetric cipher.  The client then sends that cipher key to the server.  The server uses its private key to decrypt the cipher key.  The client and server encrypt all data over the connection using the key and symmetric cipher thereafter.